# Texas Holdem Scenario... Is this possible?

Tags: nlhe

I flop the nuts – on the turn I made the best possible straight flush but am drawing dead. 
a.  What does the board look like?
b.  What are my hole cards?
c.  What does my opponent hold?

Comment: I'll take the bait. I don't think it's possible for you to both have the nut straight flush and to be drawing dead on the turn.

Comment: This Texas Hold'em Situation is not possible.

Comment: My dad always tried to teach me that there are no stupid questions :)

Comment: The best possible straight flush is T J Q K A (also called a royal flush, but not distinguished from any other straight flush except for its range. Since that's the best possible hand, no, it's not possible to be drawing dead while holding this hand.

Comment: no it is not.
you cant have the nuts and be drawing dead at the same time

Answer (score -2):

This is a semantics question. 
"The Nuts" vs "Nut Flush"
Ace hi flush (any numbers) was called the "nut flush".
Whatever cards King down make "the nuts" if they are a straight flush.
It's the James Bond hand 57 straight flush(The Nuts) to A Hi flush (Nut Flush)

Answer (score -3):

Is it a reference to this situation? 
Board 2h 4h 5h 6h 
You Ah 3h 
Opponent 7h 8h

Comment: In this answer, "you" does not have the best possible straight flush (the nuts, which "you" has on the turn per the question), thus invalidating the answer. (In fairness, it's tough to come up with a scenario that doesn't exist though.)

Answer (score -6):

A. 2♣ 8♥ 9♥ - 5♥ - T♥

B. 6♥ 7♥

C. J♥ Q♥

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the "drawing dead on the turn" criterion.

Comment: The flop doesn't give hero the nuts, which is a requirement.